# RxJava takeUntil with emmision of last item?

Tags: java, rx-java

Is there a possibility to emit item that meets condition in `takeUntil` operator?

Comment: there is Observable.last(), and lastOrDefault() operators - you can add it after Observable.takeUntil()

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mmmm not sure if I understand your question. Something like this?

```
@Test
public void tesTakeUntil() {
    List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    Observable.from(numbers)
              .takeUntil(number -> number > 3)
              .subscribe(System.out::println);

}
```

it will print

```
 1
 2
 3
 4
```

You can see more examples of Take here https://github.com/politrons/reactive/blob/master/src/test/java/rx/observables/filtering/ObservableTake.java

Comment: Let's say I have `Observable<String>` and I have `.takeUntil("foo".equals(myString))` and I would like to get this last emitted item.

Comment: Then I would use .filter(s->s.equals("foo") I think is better if you provide your code to understand what do you want to do

Answer (score 9):

With this solution, the predicate only has to be called once.

```
final String stop = "c";
Observable.just("a", "b", "c", "d")
          .takeUntil(item -> item.equals(stop))
          .lastElement()
          .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
c
```

Answer (score 6):

```
final String stop = "c";
Observable.just("a", "b", "c", "d")
          .filter(item -> !item.equals(stop))
          .takeUntil(item -> item.equals(stop))
          .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
c
```

Comment: what if my logic is really involved and I don't want to repeat it twice?

Comment: If you mean logic for filter and takeUntil, then encapsulate it in a boolean method and pass the item to it.

Comment: but with this solution, you have to call that method twice and do all the work twice...

Comment: 2 options: 1) define a side effect like final AtomicBoolean flag, set this flag before filter() with doOnNext(), then just get it in both filter and takeUntil; 2) pass boolean flag along with an item as a pair tuple.