# How to call api recursively using rxAndroid until some met condition?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-android

I am using retrofit with rxAndroid, trying to get a response from the server, until server return 0 list size.

getPageAndNext(rows_id), its accept starting point id consider for now its 0 and in next request, I will pass 9th id so that server return after 9th id response.(10th,11th,...15th...19th)

```
 Observable<List<Feed>> getPageAndNext(int id) {
        return apiInterface.postGetFeed(membersIds, id)
                .flatMap(feedResponse -> {
                    if (feedResponse.getData().size() > 0) {
                        return Observable.just(feedResponse.getData())
                                .concatWith(getPageAndNext(feedResponse.getData().get(feedResponse.getData().size() - 1).getId()));

                    }
                    return Observer::onComplete;
                });

    }
```

Here per request, I get 10 feeds and insert the feed into room database in onNext method

```
getPageAndNext(0)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                .subscribe(new DisposableObserver<List<Feed>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onNext(List<Feed> feeds) {
                        //save to room database
                        memberDatabaseRepository.insertMemberList(feeds);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        Log.e("jjjj", "error"+e);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {
                        Log.d("kkkk","done");
                    }
                });
```

Now I am not getting all response from a server. I am searching for the last 24 hours but I didn't get any solution.

Note: I am able to do 76 API calls after that never getting any response even only 76 APIs call data saved in room database. but there is around 630 API calls

Links :-

[How To Do Recursive Observable Call in RxJava?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31246088/how-to-do-recursive-observable-call-in-rxjava)

[How to ignore error and continue infinite stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28969995/how-to-ignore-error-and-continue-infinite-stream)

[RxJava takeUntil with emmision of last item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38183494/rxjava-takeuntil-with-emmision-of-last-item)

[How to make multiple requests with reactive android and retrofit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40807728/how-to-make-multiple-requests-with-reactive-android-and-retrofit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I solved recursively call API in rxAndroid.
`takeUntil` -> I am checking if I get size zero then stop recursively call.

```
Observable.range(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE)
                // Get each page in order.
                .concatMap(integer -> {
                    return apiInterface.postGetFeed(membersIds, lastFeedId);
                })
                // Take every result up to and including the one where the next page index is null.
                .takeUntil(result -> {
                    if(!result.getData().isEmpty())
                    lastFeedId = result.getData().get(result.getData().size() - 1).getId();
                    return result.getData().isEmpty();
                })
                .map(FeedResponse::getData)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(new DisposableObserver<List<Feed>>() {
                               @Override
                               public void onNext(List<Feed> feeds) {
                                   Log.d("kkkk", "" + feeds);
                                   memberDatabaseRepository.insertMemberList(feeds, lastFeedId);

                               }

                               @Override
                               public void onError(Throwable e) {
                                   Log.d("kkkk", "error " + e.getMessage());

                               }

                               @Override
                               public void onComplete() {
                                   Log.d("kkkk", "onComplete");
                                   memberDatabaseRepository.getAllFeed(FeedFragment.this);
                               }
                           }
                );
```